# IR Jammer Circuit Diagram Confusion

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, schematics, infrared

I'm fairly new to electronics so please bear with me. I was looking for a new project and found a circuit diagram of a "TV Remote Jammer" online (https://shorturl.at/doGRW). This sounded like a fun project and I probably have all the parts needed for this.

Since the pinout of the NE555 IC in the original diagram was pretty confusing to me (when trying to wire up the circuit), I tried to redraw the circuit (scheme on the right). I know that the one I have drawn looks even more confusing, but could this thing work according to my schematic?
Would this jammer work in general? (If not - why?)

[image: IR jammer schematic diagram]

Comment: your schematic diagram shows two connections that have no physical pin

Comment: @jsotola, If you imagine those two "connections" as one wire that runs under the IC instead of connecting to the IC, then it makes sense. In the left-hand diagram, there is a direct connection from pin 4 to pin 8.

Comment: yeah sorry, I forgot to mention that (the connections runs under the IC)
I ran out of space while drawing so I used this as a sloppy solution.

Comment: why do you want to use such a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that one of the wires go under the chip (which simply does not happen in schematics), the schematics are identical.

The usefulness of such a circuit is a bit questionable though. It might work, assuming your jammed device works with infrared light to begin with. Modern remotes are switching to RF, at least on higher end devices, so only cheapest or older devices will utilize IR.

You will likely have to adjust the operating frequency to be effective with some given device. However, many modern IR receiver modules have the ability to somewhat filter away the constant transmited carrier wave. So it might work, but get disappointed if it only blocks certain devices and not all devices.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Most of the TVs around me are luckily pretty old and crappy, so I might have a chance.
The tuning/adjustment will be done with the potentiometer, right?